# Как узнать количество доступной RAM памяти в macOS?

Tags: c++, память, macos, c++17

Как узнать количество доступной (не всей [Total], а той, что доступна [Available]) RAM памяти в macOS?
Для linux это выглядит так:

```
#include <fstream>

unsigned long get_mem_total() {
    std::string token;
    std::ifstream file("/proc/meminfo");
    while (file >> token) {
        if (token == "MemAvailable:") {
            unsigned long mem;
            if (file >> mem) {
                return mem;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return 0; // можете кинуть исключение
}
```

НО! `/proc/` нет в macOS...
Желательно проверить свой код перед ответом, т.к. я проверить не смогу - только уже по Feedback пойму.

Comment: посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/a/8123087/4248686

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример получения доступной памяти на MacOS

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mach/mach_host.h>

/**
 * Returns free memory in megabytes
 * https://gist.github.com/joelrfcosta/5715169
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/8782978/3004003
 */
auto
get_available_ram()
{
    // get vmstat

    auto count = HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT;
    vm_statistics_data_t vmstat;
    auto host_port = mach_host_self();
    
    if (host_statistics(host_port, HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t)&vmstat, &count) != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        // TODO: handle error
    }

    // get page size

    
    vm_size_t pagesize;
    host_page_size(host_port, &pagesize);

    // calculate available RAM

    auto mem_free = vmstat.free_count * pagesize;

    return mem_free / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
}
```

**Дополнение**

64 битная версия

```
/**
 * Warning: may return inconsistent results
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789672/why-does-host-statistics64-return-inconsistent-results
 */
auto
get_available_ram64()
{
    // get vmstat

    auto count = HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT;
    vm_statistics64_data_t vmstat;
    auto host_port = mach_host_self();
    
    if (host_statistics64(mach_host_self(), HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info64_t)&vmstat, &count) != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        // TODO: handle error
    }

    // get page size

    vm_size_t pagesize;
    host_page_size(host_port, &pagesize);

    // calculate available RAM

    auto mem_free = vmstat.free_count * pagesize;

    return mem_free / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    auto available = get_available_ram();
    std::cout << "Available " << available << " MB" << std::endl;
    
    auto available64 = get_available_ram64();
    std::cout << "Available64 " << available64 << " MB" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Здесь возвращается количество доступной памяти без SWAP?

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG не могу сказать с уверенностью, но думаю, что без свопа, поскольку для свопа `vm_stat` имеет отдельные поля (swapins/swapouts)

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG дополнил ответ 64-битной версией, есть жалобы на неверную работу метода, но для свободной памяти результаты идентичны, я проверял